# How to uninstall IIS 7 under WOW64?

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-vista, wow64

In a Web server installer that I'm maintaining, we keep track of whether or
not the installer had installed IIS 7 and/or ASP (under Vista or later) and
save an appropriate value to the Registry if so. During an uninstall, if that
value is there and no other Web sites are using IIS on that machine, the user
is asked whether or not IIS/ASP is to be removed. If so, we remove whatever
we installed.

The following is the command that we launch in order to remove IIS 7 and ASP
(line breaks added for clarity):

```
C:\Windows\system32\pkgmgr.exe /norestart /uu:IIS-WebServerRole;
IIS-WebServer;IIS-CommonHttpFeatures;IIS-StaticContent;
IIS-DefaultDocument;IIS-DirectoryBrowsing;IIS-HttpErrors;
IIS-ApplicationDevelopment;IIS-ASP;IIS-ISAPIExtensions;
IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics;IIS-HttpLogging;IIS-LoggingLibraries;
IIS-RequestMonitor;IIS-Security;IIS-RequestFiltering;
IIS-HttpCompressionStatic;IIS-WebServerManagementTools;
IIS-ManagementConsole;WAS-WindowsActivationService;
WAS-ProcessModel;WAS-NetFxEnvironment;WAS-ConfigurationAPI
```

This works fine on 32-bit systems but does not work at all on 64-bit
systems, even with WOW64 redirection disabled. (Ignore the /norestart
parameter, as the installer does a reboot at the end of the install if
necessary.) I've even tried entering this command into an admin-level command
prompt (without the /norestart parameter), but to no avail.

The command that we use during the install to install IIS 7/ASP is similarly
long, and it always works, so I can't imagine that the problem is that the
uninstall command line is too long. (To test that theory, I even tried
breaking the command into two commands, one to remove the ASP components only
followed by one to remove the rest. Same problem, nothing was removed.)

Is there some other command that would do what we want on 64-bit systems? If
so, do we have to disable WOW64 redirection, and will it also work on 32-bit
systems? (It will only be called on Vista and later systems. On earlier
systems, we rely on the user making sure that IIS and ASP are pre-installed.)

Comment: What error is returned on the 64-bit system?

Comment: how does this belong on serverfault? since when is serverfault about Windows Vista?

Comment: Because it's an operating system configuration issue? Because it's not a programming issue?

Comment: It is a programming issue in that I'm making an installer run a command. I need to know why this command won't work on a 64-bit system when similar commands (i.e., one that installs IIS 7 and ASP, one that installs just ASP (used when IIS 7 is pre-installed) and one that uninstalls just ASP) do and whether or not there is a replacement command that I can use (preferably one that also works on a 32-bit system).

Comment: @Richard: The exit code that I get back from the command on a 64-bit system is the same as on a 32-bit system: zero, which would seem to indicate that everything went well. Only IIS is not removed, even after a reboot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem that I was having doesn't have anything to do with pkgmgr.exe, unless you want to count lack of patience when doing a manual test to see why it wasn't working. In the installer, the problem was the install script doing something that prevented the command from getting launched. In the case of the manual tests, I just wasn't waiting long enough for the command to finish running. (It takes about a couple of minutes, in the case of the above command line.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this applies to your problem, but I have repeatedly been bitten by the fact that a 32 bit program that accesses the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE` key on 64 bit Windows will actually be redirected to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` key. If you are mixing 32 and 64 bit processes the 64 bit process will not have the same view of registry as the 32 bit process.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, I disable WOW64 redirection when I run the command. During installs, the (similar) command that I use to install IIS and ASP works. As do the commands for installing and uninstalling just ASP (in the case where IIS is pre-installed without ASP).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many solutions including the one given above. I simple cannot remove IIS 7 on Windows Enterprise x64
I finally ended up reinstalling IIS, and then disabling IIS Admin and World Wide Web publishing services.